# When is it best to assign property values when initializing a component?

Tags: lightning-web-components

When creating an LWC and initializing properties, should I use a Constructor to do so? or can I simply do it when declaring my component properties?

I have seen it done within a constructor and simply doing it when declaring properties, for Example:

```
export default class MyLwc extends LightningElement {
    prop1 = false;

}
```

instead of using

```
    export default class MyLwc extends LightningElement {
        prop1;
    
        constructor(){
            this.prop1 = false;
        }
    }
```

which is best when initializing properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the situation. You can't call any arbitrary initialization using the inline initialization method, so you may need to use the constructor (e.g. if you need loops or if statements, etc). Other than that, the choice is largely up to you, and they are basically the same in terms of performance, etc. The one major thing, though, is that each class should be written either with all inline initializations or in the `constructor()`. Mixing the two may lead to additional cognitive complexity when you're trying to troubleshoot problems later. Using inline initialization is usually preferred, as the code will be shorter (easier to read), but there's no hard rule that says you must do so.